# Need Help Writing Validation rule for checkbox

Tags: validation-rule

If I check the box for bulk order, I should be able to input data into the legal contract number. If data is entered in the legal contract number without the bulk order being checked an error should not appear. What validation rule should I use to confirm?

I would like the legal contract number to be a mandatory field if the bulk order is checked, but I should still be allowed to put a legal contract number even if the bulk order is not checked?

Any help as to what validation can I use for this?

Comment: can you post whatever you have tried so far

Comment: As per my understanding you want to enter a value into Contract number whether the checkbox checked or not. This is possible. If the check box is checked you must and should enter the value if not validation will fire forcing you to enter to save the record.

Answer (score 1):

For a validation rule you would use:

```
AND(Checkbox__c,ISBLANK(Legal_Number__c));
```

Comment: yes you were correct and thank you so much. It works :)